# Typescript 1.3 visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'm currently developping an app with typescript and angularJs. I'm using typescript 1.0 and i want to upgrade typescript to 1.3. Can i use typescript 1.3 with visual studio 2012 ?

Thanks.

Comment: At least there's an official extension: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/955e0262-0858-40c9-ab5a-1acc680e9bfd

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't have visual studio 2013 licence. My question is about vs 2012.

Comment: Maybe you should browse through the issues / open a new issue in the TypeScript [development repository at github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i got my answer :https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1175

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 is no longer supported, but you don't need a license for Visual Studio 2013 if you can be covered by the community edition of Visual Studio 2013...

You can download community edition / read the license here:

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx