# TypeScript 1.4 for visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I have downloaded typescript for vs2012 from the below link

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=34790

but it is giving 1.0 version but i want to work with 1.4(latest)

Is there a way to install typescript 1.4 for vs2012.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Typescript 1.4: Wrong syntax highlighting in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002810/typescript-1-4-wrong-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Typescript 1.3 visual studio 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289226/typescript-1-3-visual-studio-2012) -- See the answer in this one. It's the same for 1.4. Visual Studio 2012 is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Visual Studio 2013 or above to use the latest version of TypeScript.

There is a [free community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx), if you satisfy the licensing rules.

You can also use [Atom](https://atom.io/) (with [Atom TypeScript](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript)), [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/), [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), and a few others too - so you aren't tied to Visual Studio.